# MVP архитектура в Android приложении

Tags: android, mvp

При реализации архитектуры в виде MVP в android-приложении столкнулся с проблемой. Одна Activity содержит два Fragment'a. В этом случае у фрагментов должен быть один Presenter на двоих? или у каждого свой?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если контент у фрагментов разный и назначение у них разное - то разные Presenter.

Если всё в них одинаковое - то зачем два фрагмента?